# Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 vs Wacom Intous Pro M

Tags: wacom

It is possible to use Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 as a drawing tablet? How do you compare their capabilities? Any information will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't comparing like with like.

The Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 is an Android tablet. It won't work with professional software like Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop. You'll be limited to the drawing apps available in the Play store. However the tablet doesn't support any kind of pressure sensitivity, and therefore not so useful for drawing in my opinion.

I had a short discussion with their sales support regarding pressure sensitivity

> Me: Hi Ben. I want to know if the Yoga tab 3 10 supports pressure
>   sensitive styluses
>
> Ben J: no sorry

Wacom Intuous tablets are only input devices for use with a computer - they have no integral display, or ability to run apps. These graphics tablets are pressure sensitive, so you can have thick or thin strokes depending on how hard you press, like a real pen/pencil. They are compatible with Macs and Windows computers running software such as Adobe Photoshop/Illustrator.